# Spark To Cassandra: Writing Sparse Rows With No Null Values To Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

Q: How do I write only columns with values from a Spark DataFrame into Cassanrda and do this efficiently?
(efficiently as in minimal lines of Scala code and not creating a bunch of tombstones in Cassandra, having it run quickly, etc)

I have a Cassandra table with two key columns and 300 potential descriptor values.

```
create table sample {
    key1   text,
    key2   text,
    0      text,
    ............
    299    text,
    PRIMARY KEY (key1, key2)
}
```

I have a Spark dataframe that matches the underlying table but
each row in the dataframe is very sparse - other than the two key values, a particular row may have only 4 to 5 of the "descriptors" (columns 0->299) with a value.

I am currently converting the Spark dataframe to an RDD and using saveRdd to write the data.

This works, but "null" is stored in columns when there is no value.

For example:

```
  val saveRdd = sample.rdd

  saveRdd.map(line => (
    line(0), line(1), line(2),
    line(3), line(4), line(5),
    line(6), line(7), line(8),
    line(9), line(10), line(11),
    line(12), line(13), line(14),
    line(15), line(16), line(17),
    line(18), line(19), line(20))).saveToCassandra..........
```

Creates this in Cassandra:

XYZ |          10 | 49849 | F |                                   | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |                                        | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | TO11142017_Import | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 20 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | Scott Dick-Peddie | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |  7/13/2014 0:00 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 0 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 8 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | LOCATIONS | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | LOCATIONS | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null

Setting spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls on SparkSession does not work:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls", "true")
spark.conf.get("spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls")
```

This does not work either:

```
spark-shell  --conf spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls=true
```

(tried different ways to set this and it doesn't seem to work any way I set it)

`withColumn` and filter do not seem to be appropriate solutions.  An unset concept might be the right thing, but not sure how to use that in this case.

cassandra.3.11.2

spark-cassandra-connector:2.3.0-s_2.11

spark 2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: hi Alex., no, never found a solution and have since moved on to different pastures.  I went through your detailed answer (thank you) in the environment in question but was unable to see what your solution suggested, which is why I did not mark your answer as 'the correct one';  thx.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `ignoreNulls` doesn't work for you? Cassandra outputs `null` when there is no value in given cell. You can check if the data is really written into SSTable using the `sstabledump` tool - you'll definitely see the cells with deletion information attached (that's how nulls are stored).

Here is example of running Spark without `ignoreNulls` (default), and with `ignoreNulls` is set to `true`.  Testing was done on DSE 5.1.11, that has older version of connector, but matching to Cassandra 3.11.

Let create a test table like this:

```
create table test.t3 (id int primary key, t1 text, t2 text, t3 text);
```

without `ignoreNulls` - we need following code for testing:

```
case class T3(id: Int, t1: Option[String], t2: Option[String], t3: Option[String])
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(new T3(1, None, Some("t2"), None)))
rdd.saveToCassandra("test", "t3")
```

If we look into data using `cqlsh` we will see following:

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * from test.t3;

 id | t1   | t2 | t3
----+------+----+------
  1 | null | t2 | null

(1 rows)
```

After doing `nodetool flush` we can look into SSTables. That's what we'll see here:

```
>sstabledump mc-1-big-Data.db
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "1" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 30,
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2018-11-06T07:53:38.418171Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "t1", "deletion_info" : { "local_delete_time" : "2018-11-06T07:53:38Z" }
          },
          { "name" : "t2", "value" : "t2" },
          { "name" : "t3", "deletion_info" : { "local_delete_time" : "2018-11-06T07:53:38Z" }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can see that for columns `t1` & `t3` that were nulls there is a field `deletion_info`.

Now, let remove data with `TRUNCATE test.t3`, and start spark-shell again with `ignoreNulls` set to true:

```
dse spark --conf spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls=true
```

After executing the same Spark code we'll see same results in the `cqlsh`:

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * from test.t3;

 id | t1   | t2 | t3
----+------+----+------
  1 | null | t2 | null
```

But after performing flush, the `sstabledump` shows completely different picture:

```
>sstabledump mc-3-big-Data.db
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "1" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 27,
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2018-11-06T07:56:27.035600Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "t2", "value" : "t2" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you see, we have only data for column `t2`, and no mentions of columns `t3` & `t1` that were nulls.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. That explains it well. I faced the same issue and was confused as both kind of values - "null" and "unset" appear as null in cassandra data display. Took me a whole day to figure this out.

Comment: Although I figured it by analysing the cqlsh  logs (with "tracing on") while running "select * from <table>" query in console. Your approach gives much clear explanation.

Comment: @BdEngineer flush was need here just to illustrate tombstones fast, after every change. in production, Cassandra doing it automatically

Comment: when Cassandra don't have data on disk - it returns null - it doesn't mean that the null is stored on the disk... From code perspective you can't distinguish if you have explicit null, or data is just missing