# How can I solve error I am having while Inserting Tweet data into Apache Cassandra db?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, cassandra, tweepy

I am trying to receive tweet object using tweepy library, using Apache Kafka and Apache Spark I am trying to stream and transform json tweet object into structured format than insert it to cassandra db.

My data pipeline like below;

[image]

I have 2 .py file

1. kafka_tweet_producer.py

Written to receive tweet object filtered by desired hashtag and stream with Kafka.

2. twitter_structured_stream_spark_kafka_cassandra.py

Written to create spark session to read from kafka, transform json into structured format and finally Insert those data into Cassandra db.

I filtered tweets with my own name. Then I wrote few tweets using my pc. I saw below result;

[image]

Then I sent 1 more tweet via my mobile phone and spark session died with below error message;

```
  21/03/02 22:55:00 ERROR QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatementWrapper@40407423
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Invalid unset value for column id
21/03/02 22:55:00 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
latest exception was
  Invalid unset value for column id

Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information

        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.commit(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$7(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:450)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
21/03/02 22:55:00 ERROR DataWritingSparkTask: Aborting commit for partition 0 (task 5, attempt 0, stage 5.0)
21/03/02 22:55:00 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5)
java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
latest exception was
  Invalid unset value for column id

Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information

        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.commit(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$7(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:450)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
latest exception was
  Invalid unset value for column id
```

---

```
Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information

                at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
                at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
                at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
                at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.abort(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:51)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$12(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:473)
                at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1422)
                ... 10 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
latest exception was
  Invalid unset value for column id

Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information

                at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
                at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
                at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
                at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.close(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:56)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$15(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
                at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1433)
                ... 10 more
21/03/02 22:55:00 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
21/03/02 22:55:00 ERROR AppendDataExec: Data source write support CassandraBulkWrite(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@4d981ecd,com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector@5de27a36,TableDef(tweet_db,tweet2,ArrayBuffer(ColumnDef(id,PartitionKeyColumn,VarCharType)),ArrayBuffer(),Stream(ColumnDef(created_at,RegularColumn,TimestampType), ColumnDef(id_str,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(location,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(name,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(text,RegularColumn,VarCharType)),Stream(),false,false,Map()),WriteConf(BytesInBatch(1024),1000,Partition,LOCAL_QUORUM,false,true,5,None,TTLOption(DefaultValue),TimestampOption(DefaultValue),true,None),StructType(StructField(created_at,TimestampType,true), StructField(id_str,IntegerType,true), StructField(text,StringType,true), StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(location,StringType,true)),org.apache.spark.SparkConf@3b0b6411) is aborting.
21/03/02 22:55:00 ERROR AppendDataExec: Data source write support CassandraBulkWrite(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@4d981ecd,com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector@5de27a36,TableDef(tweet_db,tweet2,ArrayBuffer(ColumnDef(id,PartitionKeyColumn,VarCharType)),ArrayBuffer(),Stream(ColumnDef(created_at,RegularColumn,TimestampType), ColumnDef(id_str,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(location,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(name,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(text,RegularColumn,VarCharType)),Stream(),false,false,Map()),WriteConf(BytesInBatch(1024),1000,Partition,LOCAL_QUORUM,false,true,5,None,TTLOption(DefaultValue),TimestampOption(DefaultValue),true,None),StructType(StructField(created_at,TimestampType,true), StructField(id_str,IntegerType,true), StructField(text,StringType,true), StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(location,StringType,true)),org.apache.spark.SparkConf@3b0b6411) aborted.
21/03/02 22:55:00 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 774bee8a-e324-4dc4-acc7-d010fd35e74c, runId = 4c4b6718-0235-49f9-b6ee-afea8846e99b] terminated with error
py4j.Py4JException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 2442, in _call_proxy
    return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 207, in call
    raise e
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 204, in call
    self.func(DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx), batch_id)
  File "C:/Users/PC/Documents/Jupyter/Big_Data/Application_01_Kafka-twitter-spark-streaming/twitter_structured_stream_spark_kafka_cassandra.py", line 6, in write_to_cassandra
    target_df.write \
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 825, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o107.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:413)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:259)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.doExecute(V2CommandExec.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5, host.docker.internal, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
latest exception was
  Invalid unset value for column id
```

---

```
   Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information
    
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
            at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.commit(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:46)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$7(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:450)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:385)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
            Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
    latest exception was
      Invalid unset value for column id
    
    Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information
    
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
                    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.abort(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:51)
                    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$12(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:473)
                    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1422)
                    ... 10 more
            Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
    latest exception was
      Invalid unset value for column id
    
    Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information
    
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
                    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.close(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:56)
                    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$15(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
                    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1433)
                    ... 10 more
    
    Driver stacktrace:
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
            at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
            at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:382)
            ... 32 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
    latest exception was
      Invalid unset value for column id
    
    Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information
    
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
            at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.commit(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:46)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$7(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:450)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:385)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            ... 1 more
            Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
    latest exception was
      Invalid unset value for column id
    
    Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information
    
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
                    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.abort(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:51)
                    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$12(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:473)
                    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1422)
                    ... 10 more
            Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to tweet_db.tweet2. The
    latest exception was
      Invalid unset value for column id
    
    Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information
    
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
                    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
                    at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.close(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:56)
                    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$15(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
                    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1433)
                    ... 10 more
    
    
            at py4j.Protocol.getReturnValue(Protocol.java:476)
            at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:108)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.call(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1(ForeachBatchSink.scala:56)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1$adapted(ForeachBatchSink.scala:56)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:570)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:334)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/PC/Documents/Jupyter/Big_Data/Application_01_Kafka-twitter-spark-streaming/twitter_structured_stream_spark_kafka_cassandra.py", line 72, in <module>
        output_query.awaitTermination()
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\streaming.py", line 103, in awaitTermination
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 134, in deco
      File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
    pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 2442, in _call_proxy
        return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 207, in call
        raise e
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 204, in call
        self.func(DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx), batch_id)
      File "C:/Users/PC/Documents/Jupyter/Big_Data/Application_01_Kafka-twitter-spark-streaming/twitter_structured_stream_spark_kafka_cassandra.py", line 6, in write_to_cassandra
        target_df.write \
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 825, in save
        self._jwrite.save()
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
        return_value = get_return_value(
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 128, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
        raise Py4JJavaError(
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o107.save.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
```

---

```
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 774bee8a-e324-4dc4-acc7-d010fd35e74c, runId = 4c4b6718-0235-49f9-b6ee-afea8846e99b]
Current Committed Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[twitter3]]: {"twitter3":{"2":1,"1":1,"0":0}}}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[twitter3]]: {"twitter3":{"2":1,"1":1,"0":1}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
Project [to_timestamp('created_at, Some(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)) AS created_at#35, id_str#24, text#25, id#26, name#27, location#28]
+- Project [value#21.created_at AS created_at#23, value#21.id_str AS id_str#24, value#21.text AS text#25, value#21.user.id AS id#26, value#21.user.name AS name#27, value#21.user.location AS location#28]
   +- Project [from_json(StructField(created_at,StringType,true), StructField(id_str,IntegerType,true), StructField(text,StringType,true), StructField(user,StructType(StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(location,StringType,true)),true), cast(value#8 as string), Some(Asia/Istanbul)) AS value#21]
      +- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan@6859b5e7, KafkaV2[Subscribe[twitter3]]
```

You can find all my code in [this](https://github.com/euguroglu/Spark_Kafka_Stream_Twitter) repo

Comment: Not sure what's happening, but I'd bet it has to do with writing `null` values.  Usually, the Cassandra drivers utilize an "unset" capability to ensure that nulls in prepared statements don't make it into the database.  After all in Cassandra `null`==`DELETE`==tombstone.

Comment: Yes you were right, it was about difference between tweets comes from personal computer and tweets comes from mobile phone. Probably their structure are a little bit different and when i receive tweet from mobile phone id column becomes null which is primary column. @Aaron ty.

Comment: Excellent!  Converting my comment to an answer...

Comment: set `--conf spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls=true`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162033/spark-to-cassandra-writing-sparse-rows-with-no-null-values-to-cassandra/53167953#53167953

Comment: you don't even need Spark for that. Just use Kafka Connect with https://github.com/alexott/kafka-connect-twitter for reading tweets, and Kafka Connector for Cassandra (https://github.com/alexott/kafka-connect-twitter) to write into database. It will consume less resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what's happening, but I'd bet it has to do with null values. Usually, the Cassandra drivers utilize an "unset" capability to ensure that nulls in prepared statements don't make it into the database. After all in Cassandra `null`==`DELETE`==tombstone.

> when I receive tweet from mobile phone id column becomes null which is primary column.

Yes, that's got to be it.  The primary key components cannot be null in Cassandra.  Get that sent along properly, and you should be ok.

Note: When querying Cassandra using tools like `cqlsh` and showing a column which doesn't have a value, `null` will appear.  That doesn't mean that a null value is actually there.  Showing `null` is Cassandra's way of saying "no data."